# While loop not checking all conditions

Tags: java

I have a loop that should stop executing only once both jobStatus(0) and jobStatus(1) returns 2

```
while(c.getStatus(0) != 2 && c.getStatus(1) != 2){
    c.update();
}
System.out.println("Person id0:  " + c.getStatus(0));
System.out.println("Person id1:  " + c.getStatus(1));
```

Here is the update() method.

```
public void update() {      
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Person> person : allPeople.entrySet()){ //check all jobs

        Person person = person.getValue();
        if(person.getStatus() != person.WORKING){
            continue;
        }
        Date currentTime = new Date();
        long startTime = person.getStartTime().getTime();
        long requiredTime = person.getRequiredTime();
        long finishTime = startTime + requiredTime;

        if(finishTime <= currentTime.time()){
            person.finished();
            getMachineById(getAllocatedMachineId()).changeMachineStatus(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Output after loop ended:

```
Person id0:  2
Person id1:  1
```

Not sure why it's behaving the way it is, the `long` variables are correct (printing the variable reveals the current time increments correctly until it overtakes finish time - but then it exits the loop and doesn't continue for `getStatus(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop entry condition is wrong.
You could have avoided the bug by translating *what you want to do in code* leading to a *more natural*:

```
while(!(c.getJobStatus(0) == 2 && c.getJobStatus(1) == 2)){ //while both are not 2
    c.updateJobs();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You got the condition wrong. It stops when one of `c.getJobStatus(0)` and `c.getJobStatus(1)` is two.

It should be:

```
while(c.getJobStatus(0) != 2 || c.getJobStatus(1) != 2){
    c.updateJobs();
}
```

As long as one of them is not two, the loop should continue.